# Sybase: Incorrect syntax near 'go' in a 'IF EXISTS' block

Tags: t-sql, sybase

This is my sql statement

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE')
  drop table dbo.PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE
go
```

isql bails out with this error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1:
Server 'DB_SERVER', Line 3:
Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
```

But the sql statement look correct to me. What's wrong?

Sybase version is 15

Comment: Please ignore that. I was using vi to inspect if I have inadvertently included some rubbish invisible characters, and then copy and pasted to SO here. I removed other marker but missed this one. '$' just mean EOL here.

Comment: Wow - thought MS bought and swallowed anything sybaseish

Comment: And how are you invoking this query?

Comment: @adriy I use isql in a bash shell

Comment: Your problem may have an explanation similar to the one [mentioned here](http://osdir.com/ml/db.squirrel-sql.users/2007-12/msg00006.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE')
  drop table dbo.PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE

go
```

or this:

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE')
BEGIN
  drop table dbo.PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE
END

go
```

or this:

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE')
BEGIN
  select 1
END

go
```

---

**Does any work?**

Comment: The link is linked to MySQL reference. My question is about TSQL/Sybase

Answer (score 0):

`GO` is not a keyword of T-SQL, but of the editor.

SMSS (between others) uses it as 'division' between batches of commands it sends to the database server. Executing it inside a stored procedure, or even a script file, won't work.

edit: Maybe it works with SyBase, but I think it'll need to be uppercase in that case.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the `GO` statement is a command of the editor you're using, not `SQL` itself:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.

That said - Sybase is also an editor that supports the `GO` statement.

I've had the same problem, but with SQL Management Studio. The issue is that the editor does not support mixed-newline types around certain statements - `GO` being one of them. In Management Studio, for example, only Windows-style newlines (CR + LF) are allowed and if I were to use the Linux format (LF), it will give the exact same error as yours above.

Text-editors such as Notepad++ (what I use) have an option for what type of End-of-Line characters you use by default (Windows, Linux, Mac (CR)).

Try checking what newline character(s) are being used in your statements to see if that can fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the object reference have

dbo..PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE

because you haven't given a database name, and if you include the obj owner you need .. to miss the db name?

I'd go:

EXEC('DROP TABLE dbo..PNL_VALUE_ESTIMATE')

in the true part as well, because DROP TABLE is always compiled, and if the table isn't there you'll still have a failure.

Do you even need dbo?  If your sql always runs as dbo just leave it out.

Comment: I thought .. was for skipping the schema name, not for skipping the db name.